# how to count occurrence of specific word in group of file by bash/shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

i have two text files 'simple' and 'simple1' with following data in them

```
    simple.txt--

    hello
    hi hi hello
    this
    is it

    simple1.txt--
    hello hi
    how are you



[]$ tr ' ' '\n' < simple.txt | grep  -i -c '\bh\w*'
4
[]$ tr ' ' '\n' < simple1.txt | grep  -i -c '\bh\w*'
3
```

this commands show the  number of words that start with "h" for each file but i want to display the total count to be 7 i.e. total of both file. Can i do this in single command/shell script?

P.S.: I had to write two commands as tr does not take two file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alternative requires no pipelines:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '/^h/{i++} END{print i+0}' simple.txt simple1.txt
7
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS='[[:space:]]+'`

  This tells awk to treat each word as a record.
- `/^h/{i++}`

  For any record (word) that starts with `h`, we increment variable `i` by 1.
- `END{print i+0}`

  After we have finished reading all the files, we print out the value of `i`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, the straightforward way :

```
cat simple.txt simple1.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | grep  -i -c '\bh\w*'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the case, that tr accepts only one filename, it does not accept any filename (and always reads from stdin). That's why even in your solution, you didn't provide a filename for tr, but used input redirection.

In your case, I think you can replace `tr` by `fmt`, which does accept filenames:

```
fmt -1 simple.txt simple1.txt | grep -i -c -w 'h.*'
```

(I also changed the *grep* a bit, because I personally find it better readable this way, but this is a matter of taste).

Note that both solutions (mine and your original ones) would count a string consisting of letters and one or more non-space characters - for instance the string *haaaa.hbbbbbb.hccccc* - as a "single block", i.e. it would only add 1 to the count of "h"-words, not 3. Whether or not this is the desired behaviour, it's up to you to decide.